# android Error:(44, 13) Failed to resolve com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.7

Tags: android, sdk, maps, arcgis, esri

Every time I build my android project it gives me this Error

```
android Error:(44, 13) Failed to resolve com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.7
```

Can anyone help me regarding this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved like that 
1.

add the following lines

```
 // Add the following ArcGIS repository
        maven {
            url 'https://esri.bintray.com/arcgis'
        }
```

in the build.gradle of the project module

to be like that

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.


buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        //**Added .. for ArcGIS
        maven {
            url 'https://esri.bintray.com/arcgis'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        // Add the following ArcGIS repository
        maven {
            url 'https://esri.bintray.com/arcgis'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Also , I edited the version of arcgis dependency in the app module build.gradle to be like that

```
compile 'com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.8'
```

Comment: The additional maven url under **buildscript** helped me solve my issue!

Answer (score 0):

May be needful.

In the app module build.gradle file, within the dependencies block, add a directive to include the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android dependency to your app.
App module build.gradle file

[Fallow all the steps from here](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/guide/install-and-set-up.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_C9913E8160D74241977115BEA470E1C3)

```
dependencies {
    // Add ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android dependency
    compile 'com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.7'
}
```

Comment: Already done ... that's why I am having the above error ! It can't resolve this line

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to version mis-match of Android Studio. So, try giving latest dependencies in app level build.gradle. In my case I changed it from 10.2.6 to 10.2.8

```
compile 'com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.8'
```